# How can I put data from my database in a multidimensional array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to put the retrieved data from my database in a multidimensional array.

`get_questions()` function is `"SELECT * FROM statement";`

```
$statements = Questions::get_questions();
$datas = array();

foreach($statements as $statement){
   array_push($datas, $statement["order"], $statement["statement"], $statement["statement"], $statement["questionnaire_id"]);
}

print_r($datas);
```

Then I retrieve just a normal array. How do I put this in a multidimensional array with the data per question?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Do you want to push each iteration in your foreach into a single array key?
`$datas[] = ["order"=>$statement["order"], "statement"=> $statement["statement"]...]`

Comment: Need to show what you get and what you want.

Comment: @BrettGregson I want it to look like this:

Comment: array(
array(1, “statement1”, “statement2”, 1),
array(2, “statement1”, “statement2”, 1),
array(3, “statement1”, “statement2”, 1),
array(4, “statement1”, “statement2”, 1),
array(5, “statement1”, “statement2”, 1) … )

Comment: `$datas[] = [ $statement["order"], $statement["statement"], $statement["statement"], $statement["questionnaire_id"] ];` maybe?

Comment: @onadm Cool, my example should work (if you want named keys), otherwise remove the keys: `$datas[] = [$statement["order"], $statement["statement"]...]`